# How to highlight a specific word in tkinter?

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I need to highlight a specific word in a text within a tkinter frame. In order to find the word, I put a balise like in html. So in a text like "hello i'm in the |house|" I want to highlight the word "house".

My frame is defined like that:

`class FrameCodage(Frame):
      self.t2Codage = Text(self, height=20, width=50)`

and I insert my text with this code: `fenetre.fCodage.t2Codage.insert(END, res)` , res being a variable containing my text.

I saw this code on an other post:

```
class CustomText(tk.Text):
'''A text widget with a new method, highlight_pattern()

example:

text = CustomText()
text.tag_configure("red", foreground="#ff0000")
text.highlight_pattern("this should be red", "red")

The highlight_pattern method is a simplified python
version of the tcl code at http://wiki.tcl.tk/3246
'''
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

def highlight_pattern(self, pattern, tag, start="1.0", end="end",
                      regexp=False):
    '''Apply the given tag to all text that matches the given pattern

    If 'regexp' is set to True, pattern will be treated as a regular
    expression.
    '''

    start = self.index(start)
    end = self.index(end)
    self.mark_set("matchStart", start)
    self.mark_set("matchEnd", start)
    self.mark_set("searchLimit", end)

    count = tk.IntVar()
    while True:
        index = self.search(pattern, "matchEnd","searchLimit",
                            count=count, regexp=regexp)
        if index == "": break
        self.mark_set("matchStart", index)
        self.mark_set("matchEnd", "%s+%sc" % (index, count.get()))
        self.tag_add(tag, "matchStart", "matchEnd")
```

But they are few things that I don't understand: how can I apply this function to my case? When did I call this function? What's the pattern and the tag in my case? I'm a beginner in Tkinter so don't hesitate to explain to me this code, or another.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
class FrameCodage(Frame):
    self.t2Codage = Text(self, height=20, width=50)
```

... do this:

```
class FrameCodage(Frame):
    self.t2Codage = CustomText(self, height=20, width=50)
```

Next, create a "highlight" tag, and configure it however you want:

```
self.t2Codage.tag_configure("highlight", foreground="red")
```

Finally, you can call the `highlight_pattern` method as if it were a standard method:

```
self.t2Codage.highlight_pattern(r"\|.*?\|", "red", regexp=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. "CustomText" send me an error "not defined". Plus, I don't input my text in my frame in the same class than FrameCodage. Then, how I call my function? I tried "FrameCodage.t2Codage.highlight_pattern(...)" but it doesn't work.

Just in order to be sure, I have to define the tag just after the " self.t2Codage = Text(self, height=20, width=50)" ?

Comment: @pioupiou1211: you have to add the tag after you create the widget; before you create it it's impossible to call. It doesn't matter where or when you insert the text. After you insert the text you can call the `highlight_text` method. It won't happen automatically.

Comment: Ok, then i called the method before inserting the text as it doesn't matter. But I have this error: `self.t2Codage.highlight_pattern(r"\|.*?\|", "red", regexp=True)
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'highlight_pattern'`

Comment: @pioupiou1211: read the error message. Notice how it says `'Text' object`? If you were using this class it would say `'CustomText' object`.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I didn't understand that I had to create the class CustomText. Now everything is set up but I don't know how to call the method. After that I input the text, I did `fenetre.fCodage.t2Codage.highlight_pattern(r"\|.*?\|", "red", regexp=True) ` but it doesn't work. I got no error message but nothing is highlighted.

Comment: Just in case, I did this for the tag: 

`self.t2Codage = CustomText(self, height=20, width=50)
self.t2Codage.tag_configure("highlight",foreground="red")`

Answer (score 1):

Below is widget I created to deal with this, hope it helps.

```
try: import tkinter as tk
except ImportError: import Tkinter as tk

class code_editor(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent, case_insensetive = True, current_line_colour = '', word_end_at = r""" .,{}[]()=+-*/\|<>%""", tags = {}, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda e: self.highlight())
        
        self.case_insensetive = case_insensetive
        self.highlight_current_line = current_line_colour != ''
        self.word_end = word_end_at
        self.tags = tags
        
        if self.case_insensetive:
            for tag in self.tags:
                self.tags[tag]['words'] = [word.lower() for word in self.tags[tag]['words']]
        
        #loops through the syntax dictionary to creat tags for each type
        for tag in self.tags:
            self.tag_config(tag, **self.tags[tag]['style'])
        
        if self.highlight_current_line:
            self.tag_configure("current_line", background = current_line_colour)
            self.tag_add("current_line", "insert linestart", "insert lineend+1c")
            self.tag_raise("sel")
        
    #find what is the last word thats being typed.
    def last_word(self):
        line, last = self.index(tk.INSERT).split('.')
        last=int(last)
        
        #this limit issues when user is a fast typer
        last_char = self.get(f'{line}.{int(last)-1}', f'{line}.{last}')
        while last_char in self.word_end and last > 0:
            last-=1          
            last_char = self.get(f'{line}.{int(last)-1}', f'{line}.{last}')
            
        first = int(last)
        while True:
            first-=1
            if first<0: break
            if self.get(f"{line}.{first}", f"{line}.{first+1}") in self.word_end:
                break
        return {'word': self.get(f"{line}.{first+1}", f"{line}.{last}"), 'first': f"{line}.{first+1}", 'last': f"{line}.{last}"}
    
    #highlight the last word if its a syntax, See: syntax dictionary on the top.
    #this runs on every key release which is why it fails when the user is too fast.
    #it also highlights the current line
    def highlight(self):
        
        if self.highlight_current_line:
            self.tag_remove("current_line", 1.0, "end")
            self.tag_add("current_line", "insert linestart", "insert lineend+1c")
        
        lastword = self.last_word()
        wrd = lastword['word'].lower() if self.case_insensetive else lastword['word']
        
        for tag in self.tags:
            if wrd in self.tags[tag]['words']:
                self.tag_add(tag, lastword['first'], lastword['last'])
            else:
                self.tag_remove(tag, lastword['first'], lastword['last'])
        
        self.tag_raise("sel")
        
#### example ####
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # from pyFilename import code_editor
    
    ms = tk.Tk()
    
    example_text = code_editor(
        parent = ms,
        case_insensetive = True, #True by default.
        current_line_colour = 'grey10', #'' by default which will not highlight the current line.
        word_end_at = r""" .,{}[]()=+-*/\|<>%""", #<< by default, this will till the class where is word ending.
        tags = {#'SomeTagName': {'style': {'someStyle': 'someValue', ... etc}, 'words': ['word1', 'word2' ... etc]}} this tells it to apply this style to these words
            "failSynonyms": {'style': {'foreground': 'red', 'font': 'helvetica 8'}, 'words': ['fail', 'bad']},
            "passSynonyms":{'style': {'foreground': 'green', 'font': 'helvetica 12'}, 'words': ['Pass', 'ok']},
            "sqlSyntax":{'style': {'foreground': 'blue', 'font': 'italic'}, 'words': ['select', 'from']},
            },
        font='helvetica 10 bold',   #Sandard tkinter text arguments
        background = 'black',       #Sandard tkinter text arguments
        foreground = 'white'        #Sandard tkinter text arguments
    )    
    
    example_text.pack()
    ms.mainloop()
```